# How do I read RAM memory labels?

Tags: memory

I have a stick of RAM but I don't know what frequency it works at. All I know is that is DDR2. See the photo below:

[image: How to read the label?]

I assume it's 533 MHz, but how can I read the label to be sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label says PC2-4200U, so we look that up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM#Chips_and_modules), and see that it is 533Mhz, with a transfer rate of 4267 MT/S, and JEDEC timing profiles for 3-3-3-11.25 and 4-4-4-15.

Comment: i checked the same page but didn't find the info, what's the voltage it works at?

Comment: hold up, i found it now, thx

Comment: Look at the section under the header "Chips and Modules" at the row where Module Name is "PC2-4200*"

Comment: voltage is 1.8 volts ?

Comment: The JEDEC spec says 1.8-1.9 (max normal), but must withstand operation at up to 2.3v for short periods to make the ram more resistant to power surges and to allow greater freedom for overclocking. This is standard for DDR2 of all subtypes, not just PC2-4200. Because there is only the one voltage spec for the whole DDR2 series, the label did not choose to mention it.